# Appending list using jQuery is conflicting with the rest of site

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, append

Another quick question. I'm appending a list using jQuery and outside of my site it is working fine, when I place it within my code it seems to be conflicting and turning other elements on my page into lists. Is there an ID I can give this code and if so where would I place it to differentiate it to the rest of the spans/lists on my site?

js fiddle included http://bit.ly/1bCnC1D

Thanks

Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no way of seeing if these edits fix the issue, as I can't view the rest of your site to see the effects my edits have, but here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxKRY/1/) in which I added an ID to your dynamically created list. Hopefully it'll do the trick.

```
  $(function(){
    $('#populate').click(function(){  
      $('#testing').append('<ul id="testingUL"/>');
      $('#textHolder>span').each(function(){
        $('#testingUL').append('<li>' + $(this).text()  + '</li>' );

      }); 
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an ID to the `<ul>` to hopefully prevent the issue you're currently having.

```
$(function(){
    $('#populate').click(function(){  
        $('#testing').append('<ul id="list" />');
        $('#textHolder>span').each(function(){
            $('#list').append('<li>' + $(this).text()  + '</li>' );
        }); 
    });
});
```

Notice that I also changed the element that the `<li>`s are being appended to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume other elements on your page have the id of "textHolder". That is not good practice. Try having each of your element's ids be unique. To get this to work, you should rename your id="textHolder" to something unique. If you wish to effect a group of elements all at once, you can use a class in jquery instead of an id.